# Unusual network activity

Tags: network-monitoring

I noticed that my network monitor was showing intense activity (mostly download at high rates) even though my browser wasnt loading any pages. I installed nethogs and checked the usage and got the below result. 
(I took the screenshot right after reconnecting my modem. That is why the sent/received section is showing empty values. But it goes up later on)

[image: nethogs output]

Could anyone please let me know what these programs are. Should I be concerned?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, this output isn't really helpful. Use `sudo netstat -ntp` to show the processes responsible for the connections. Please include that output in your question. And please copy&paste in text form - there's no need to screenshot terminal output, you see? ;) http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/88802

Comment: Thanks for the info, i tried `sudo netstat -ntp` and it turns out to be the local addesses for google-chrome. I had copy&pasted the output,but it wasnt formatted correctly. Will do so in future.

Comment: @gertvdijk If you could change the comment to a reply, I could mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of those are Google owned IP addresses. I suspect its the google safe browsing service, which provides a list of known malware/phising URLs